# Base64 Encoding difference in a particular String

Tags: rest, http, encoding, utf-8, base64

I have a doubt. It's regarding Base64 encoding of one particular String.

We have an application which allows REST WebServices to be executed after authorization of type Basic Authentication is successful.

I has set the password for a user **USER_NAME** with the password **CP@5N0v22nD17RrV8f4​**.

From my system, using Postman/Advanced REST client, the request sent is processed successfully. But the same request fails when made most of the other systems using the same REST client.

When I set this password to another user, that user credentials is facing the same problem.

I noticed that the Base64 encoding Output Charset is the problem. But there is no method to change it in the REST clients (*not in the most of the ready-made ones*).

But why is this happening only for this particular password. I check with every other passwords and it works fine.

**String:** USER_NAME:CP@5N0v22nD17RrV8f4​
**UTF-8:** VVNFUl9OQU1FOkNQQDVOMHYyMm5EMTdSclY4ZjTigIs=
**Windows-1252:** VVNFUl9OQU1FOkNQQDVOMHYyMm5EMTdSclY4ZjQ=
**ASCII:** VVNFUl9OQU1FOkNQQDVOMHYyMm5EMTdSclY4ZjQ=

Only for ***CP@5N0v22nD17RrV8f4***​ the UTF-8 output charset encoding in Base64 is giving a different result.
Using any other passwords, all the outputs are the same.

Please make me understand why ***CP@5N0v22nD17RrV8f4​*** is different from the rest of the strings.

Thanks in Advance
Balu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string has a [non breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) at the end of the string.

I tested this using the following steps.

1. Decoded the  UTF-8 string VVNFUl9OQU1FOkNQQDVOMHYyMm5EMTdSclY4ZjTigIs= at https://www.base64decode.org/
2. Copied the result to encode in UTF-8 at https://www.base64decode.org/, but this time pressed backspace once at the end of string. Gives me output VVNFUl9OQU1FOkNQQDVOMHYyMm5EMTdSclY4ZjQ=

You could also try typing the characters manually, and encoding.

Comment: Thanks Ashish. It's as you said.

Now that I think about it, I first updated the password in a document and then copied from there, and sent it to the user.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)